# Extended classes and static values

Tags: php, inheritance, static

I'm trying to understand how PHP manages memory and variables with static methods in extended classes. I've got three classes one entitled Model, User1, User2. Hence:

```
class Model {
    static public $structure;
    static public $name;
    static function get_structure() {
        return self::$structure = file_get_contents(self::$name.'.json');
    }
}
class User1 extends Model {

}
class User2 extends Model {

}
User1::$name = 'User1';
User2::$name = 'User2';
echo User1::get_structure();
echo User2::get_structure();
```

If I run User1::get_structure(); for some reason it doesn't populate the result accordingly, it seems to be grabbing the value of User2 (the last $name value declared).

I'm operating on the assumption that declaring User2 and extending Model creates a completely separate scope for my $name property. So User1 and User2 are declared as separate classes with the same structure as Model. Then I can statically define values for them in separate scopes.

I'm now however questioning that. If I extend and call the same $name variable do they both point back to the Model class? Or does it only create a separate scope when I declare each class with new User1(); and new User2();?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are using static classes, it is not OOP. I am removing the tag. Also, model is a [layer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5864000/727208) , not a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this behavior, because you are accessing same variable

```
class X
{
    public static $data = null;
}

class Foo extends X{};
class Bar extends X{};

Foo::$data = 'lorem ipsum';
echo Bar::$data;
// :: output :: lorem ipsum;
```

Your `$name` variable stays tied to the `Model` class, even in inherited classes.

Comment: Excellent, that confirms precisely what I'm thinking. Thank you.

Comment: @pilotguy, I would actually recommend for you to try to avoid static variable. A static variable in class act like namespaced `global`. While syntax is changed, they both have same behavior and same problem that are associated with [global state](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FRm3VPhseI).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all classes that extends **Model** will point back to the same $name variable.
Sees static variable as a "global" variable.

Maybe this example will clarify you:

```
class Model 
{
    static public $name;
}

class User1 extends Model 
{
    public function setName( $name )
    {
        parent::$name = $name;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return parent::$name;
    }
}

class User2 extends Model 
{
    public function setName( $name )
    {
        parent::$name = $name;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return parent::$name;
    }
}

$user1 = new User1();
$user1->setName("User1");

$user2 = new User2();
$user1->setName("User2");

echo $user1->getName();
echo $user2->getName();

// Output : User2User2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can work around it with:

```
<?php
class Model {
    static public $structure;
    static public $name;
    static function get_structure() {
        $class = get_called_class();
        return $class::$structure = file_get_contents($class::$name.'.json');
    }
}
class User1 extends Model {
    static public $structure;
    static public $name;
}
class User2 extends Model {
    static public $structure;
    static public $name;
}
User1::$name = 'User1';
User2::$name = 'User2';
echo User1::get_structure();
echo User2::get_structure();
```

... but, you might ask yourself the question whether this design is the proper one. atm it for instance looks like they should be instances with separate values & instance methods, but that might be because of the condensed example.

Comment: Hmmmm this is a pretty good idea. My goal is to not force the user to instantiate the model layer until they absolutely have to. It's for ease of coding + I bet I can argue that it's good for performance as well. I'm considering a model simply an adapter to the db...all my returned datasets are framework specific "record" objects that point back to the model.